# IB API - Cancel historic market data request if no data received

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers

I am doing historic market data requests for several stocks. I often get the problem, that my loop through a ticker id list stops at a certain point and doesn't go any further. There is also no error code received that I could react on in this specific case.

My code is the following:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.common import BarData

for i in range(len(df)):

        class MyWrapper(EWrapper):

            def nextValidId(self, orderId:int):
                self.nextValidOrderId = orderId
                self.start()

            def historicalData(self, reqId:int, bar: BarData):
                print("HistoricalData. ReqId:", reqId, "BarData.", bar)

            def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):

                print("Error. Id: " , reqId, " Code: " , errorCode , " Msg: " , errorString)

                if errorCode == 200 or errorCode == 162:
                    app.disconnect()

            def historicalDataEnd(self, reqId: int, start: str, end: str):
                app.disconnect()

            def start(self):
                queryTime = df.iloc[i]["Date"]
                contract = Contract()
                contract.symbol = df.iloc[i]["IBS"]
                contract.secType = 'STK'
                contract.exchange = 'IBIS'
                contract.currency = "EUR"

                app.reqHistoricalData(4102, contract, queryTime,"1 D", "1 day", "MIDPOINT", 1, 1, False, [])

        app = EClient(MyWrapper())
        app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, clientId=123) 
        app.run()
```

I figured out the problem may be, that I queried historic data for a stock earlier in time than it is available. An example for this is the ticker ID "14D1" with historic data of the day 08/20/2021 (20. Aug. 2021). In TWS I see that there is no historic data earlier than 10/05/2021 but I dont get an error message when requesting data ealier than this data, the code just runs forever without a result.

Since I can't react to any error message given, I think I need something that allows my code to proceed to the next ticker ID in the dataframe if the code takes for a ticker too long (like more than a few seconds). Or a command to receive the latest historic data point for a stock so I could adapt my queryTime request.

Any help here would be massively appreciated!

Comment: you could define class outside `for`-loop, and send `i` as argument in `__init__`

Comment: what is `EClient` ?` What is `EWrapper` ? We have no idea what module you use, so we have no idea how it work, and how to help you, And we can't read in your mind. You have to add all details in question (not in comments)

Comment: maybe you should use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"`. Maybe if you will see what you have in variables then you will see how to detect end of data and then stop it. OR maybe you should run `for`-loop inside wrapper to change `contract.symbol` when you get end of data

Comment: Hey Furas, thank you for your comments :) I added the modules in the code. I think I figured out a solution now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out a solution for this problem:

In the IB APU there is a function available that gives you the last available data point of a stock. You can find it here:

https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/head_timestamp.html#reqHeadTimeStamp

It allows you to skip a stock that has no data for your requested date which is exactly what I need.

Comment: you can mark your own answer as accepted. And few minutes later you can upvote it.